# Why won't C compile if two separate source files in the same workspace share function names?

Tags: c, eclipse, linker

I'm using eclipse indigo, gcc and cdt in a project. If two functions in separate source files share names (regardless of return type or parameters), eclipse flags a redefinition error. This isn't a huge issue regarding this project given I can easily rename these functions, and I'm well aware of wrappers if it were. Although this isn't a critical issue, it does make me think I'm not understanding the c build process. What occurs during the build process in which a program structure like this would cause issue?

**Here's some more info. on the situation, and where my understanding is so far -- not necessary to answer the question, although there must be a hole in my understanding.**

In this case, the two functions are intended to be used only locally, as such their prototypes are not given in the .h interface, and for the sake of my point, neither are defined 'static'.

Neither of these source files are being included anywhere in the project, so they shouldn't be sharing any compilation units. With that in consideration, I would have assumed that the neither source file is aware of the presence of the other, and the compiler would have no problem indexing the two functions, as the separate files would allow for proper distinguishing between the two during linking -- so long as they weren't included in the same compilation unit.

I noticed that statically defining either instance of the function declaration removes the error. I remember reading at some point that every function not declared static is global -- although given these functions are not a part of the .h interface, the practical example in which including the .h interface doesn't allow for the including program to reference all .c functions would indicate "hiding" these functions would be of no issue.

What am I overlooking?

Some insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the concept of "linkage".  Every function and variable in C has a linkage type, one of "external", "internal", and "none".  (Only variables can have no linkage.)

Functions have external linkage by default, which means that they can be called by name from any compilation unit (where "compilation unit" roughly means one source file and all the headers it includes).  This can be expressed explicitly by declaring them `extern`, or it can be overridden by declaring them `static`.  Functions declared `static` have internal linkage, meaning they can be referenced by name only from other functions in the same compilation unit.

No two external functions anywhere in the same program can have the same name, regardless of header files, but static functions in different compilation units may have the same name.  A static function may have the same name as an external function, too -- then the name resolves to the static function within its compilation unit, and to the external function elsewhere.  These restrictions make sense, for otherwise it would be possible for a function call to be ambiguous.

Header files don't factor into the linkage equation at all.  They are primarily a vehicle for sharing declarations, but a function's linkage depends only on *how* it is declared, not on *where*.

I leave discussion of variables' linkage for another time.

Answer (score 0):

> remember reading at some point that every function not declared static is global

Having understood this you got the main point and reason for the behaviour observed.

.h files are not known to the linker, after pre-processing there are only translation units left (typically a .c file with all includes merged in), from which .o files are compiled.

There are no interfaces on language level in C.

> Neither of these source files are being included anywhere in the project, so they shouldn't be sharing any compilation units.

Declare those functions as `static`. This is the only way to "hide" a function from the linker "inside" a translation unit.

Comment: Right, and thanks for the answer. I came to the same conclusion as to you what you advised. Perhaps interface is too OOD of a concept, however the logic in separation still holds. 

So if the **why** of it really is just an issue of global variables -- what are the technicals of how a wrapper solves this issue? Would this not also imply the function being wrapped would still be indistinguishably visible from the linker's perspective?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether one source module includes headers for another.  Header files only contain declarations for the purpose of local functions being able to find functions in other modules.  It doesn't mean that functions not declared don't exist from the perspective of that module.

When everything gets linked together, anything not specifically defined to be local to one source module (i.e. `static`) has to have a unique name across all linked components.

Comment: I'm well aware of these tenants. This does not address my question as to what occurs during the compilation/linker process that would give rise to an issue.

Comment: @TolkienWASP I wouldn't exactly call it an issue.  That's the way the linker works, and that's the restriction you need to work with when programming in C.

Comment: There is no explanation in your answer as to **how** it works. My question was not coming from an inability to distinguish the rules.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't "mangle" function names the way C++ or Java do (since C doesn't support function polymorphism).

For example, in C++, the functions

```
void foo( void );
void foo( int x );
void foo( int x, double y );
```

have their names "mangled" into the unique symbols<sup>1</sup>

```
_Z3fooid
_Z3fooi 
_Z3foov
```

which is how overloaded function/method calls are disambiguated at the machine level.

C doesn't do that; instead, the linker sees two different function definitions using the same symbol and yaks because it has no way to disambiguate the two.

---

<sup>1. This is what happens on my system, anyway</sup>